# Customize Amcharts v4 tooltip border color

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4

I've applied code like this:

```
var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series.tooltip.getFillFromObject = false;
series.tooltip.background.fill = am4core.color("#fff");
series.tooltip.border.fill = am4core.color("#000");
series.tooltip.label.fill = am4core.color("#000");
series.tooltipText = "{date.formatDate('d MMM, yyyy')}: [bold]{value}";
series.dataFields.dateX = "date";
series.dataFields.valueY = "value";
```

But somehow tooltip is not loaded with border color.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In amcharts the field for the border color is `stroke`. You can set it eiter on the [`tooltip`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/tooltip/) itself, on the [`tooltip.background`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/tooltip/#background) or on the [`tooltip.label`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/tooltip/#label). For example like this:

```
series.tooltip.background.stroke = am4core.color("#000");
```

You also can change the border width using `strokeWidth`:

```
series.tooltip.background.strokeWidth = 2;
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wLXmbr) is a working code pen.